# Adobe Flex - Race Condition Bug?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, mxml

I am running into an issue when interacting with the Adobe Flex application.  However, in Debug mode I cannot reproduce the problem.

I am updating a Flex `DataGrid` when a separate textbox (select) is changed.

Based on a flag value related to the value when the textbox is set:

If flag == true, 
   I add an additional `DataGridRow` of type T to the `DataGrid` (if it does not already exist) 
If flag == false,
   I remove the `DataGridRow` of type T if it already exists.

This seems to work in about 95% of cases.  There is a certain point that my app reaches, where even if the flag of that textbox is set to true, the `DataGridRow` is not ADDED, even though it is supposed to.  Once this point is reached, every time from this point forward, the flag for this value in the textbox no longer causes the `DataGridRow` to be added.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions in debugging this issue?

Comment: Show some code. It's impossible to tell from your description only.

Comment: This cannot be an actual race condition, because your code is not multithreaded, and thus there is no real concurrency. Logical error, missing conditionals, maybe. However, this sounds like a "silent" null pointer exception to me: At some point, something in your if-statement is null, causes the script to fail, and then prevents the rest of the program from functioning normally. Why you don't get any error messages is beyond my comprehension, though. And telling for sure is impossible without additional information, or code samples.